# How to use Int index to String element

Tags: java, collections

Can you help me with this? I don't have any idea how to fix my code. I want to get the index from IDnumber using binarySearch from collections then I will use that IDnumber's index to get the element from the Names but Im having a problem.

I got some errors when Im running it but I dont see any errors here in NetBeans.

Here is the whole code.

```
public class Attendance {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        List <Integer> IDnumber = Arrays.asList(121,122,123,124,125);
        List <String> Names = Arrays.asList("Victor","Arvin","Marthie","Mariam","Argel");
        System.out.println("Log In");

        System.out.println("Enter your Student number : ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int StudentNumber = scanner.nextInt(); 

        int x = StudentNumber;
        String s = Names.get(x);

        System.out.println(Collections.binarySearch(IDnumber,x));
        System.out.println(" Student Name : " + s);

    }
}
```

Can I pass the Int index to String?

Comment: Your collections arent sorted, you can't use binary search on unsorted collections. Sort them first.

Comment: So i need to sort the two List? or only the Names?

Comment: Actually his IDnumber is sorted.

Comment: Your collections are small, and you can verify by hand if one is or isn't sorted.

Comment: I will add more if my code will work.

Comment: In addition to the sorting issue with binary searching - there's also a relationship issue and he should probably be using a Map instead.  Hand verification is possible here but not good practice since it looks like he's trying to build a database of potentially many students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is to assign `StudentNumber` to `x`. Instead you should do

```
int x = Collections.binarySearch(IDnumber, StudentNumber)
```

Then you will get the index of the student with the number entered (121, for example).

Then you get the name of the student like you do

```
String s = Names.get(x);
```

Comment: Exactly, I was about to post this. He was passing the IDNumber as the index. Obviously, index 121,122, etc. do not exist in that Array.

Comment: I didnt practice java in 3 months so im having a trouble. BTW, your answer works with my code. Thank you.

Comment: This is really not such a great answer.  It depends on so many things: the IDNumbers being in sorted order, IDs being at the same index as the corresponding student name, etc.  ...and, for short lists, BinarySearch time is essentially the same as just scanning the list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a Map:

```
private static final Map<Integer, String> STUDENTS;
static {
    Map<Integer, String> m = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    m.put(Integer.valueOf(121), "Victor");
    m.put(Integer.valueOf(122), "Arvin");
    m.put(Integer.valueOf(123), "Marthie");
    m.put(Integer.valueOf(124), "Mariam");
    m.put(Integer.valueOf(125), "Argel");
    STUDENTS = Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);
}
```

then...

```
String s = STUDENTS.get(scanner.nextInt());
```

Answer (score 1):

If the user enters their student number (say, 121), you're trying to do this:

`String s = Names.get(121);`

When there is no value at the index 121 in `Names`.  `Names` is only 5 elements long.  What you want to do is look up the student number in `IDnumber` list, then use that index of the ID as the index into `Names`.

Try something like:

```
int idIndex = IDnumber.indexOf(x);
String s = Names.get(idIndex);
```

Although you might consider using a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to store the relationship between the Name and the ID.  What you're doing here heavily depends on the order of the IDs and Names - any shift in the ordering and your relationship is lost.

Answer (score 0):

you get the value from the list of **Names**  which contains only index of 4 .

Hence values after 4 will give **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

Answer (score 0):

You should sort the Collection before you can do a binarysearch on it:
Use:

```
Collections.sort( IDnumber );
System.out.println(Collections.binarySearch(IDnumber,x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
int index = Names.indexOf(StudentNumber);
```

Once you have this you know the index for both the ID and the name; you don't need to do the binary search (which depends your list of IDs staying in order, and will break if not).  (Binary search would be faster - but the gain is insignificant unless your list is *huge*.)

Or do you actually want them to type in 0, 1, 2, (etc) and not 121, 122, 123, (etc)?

BTW.  Please use Java conventions - e.g. variables should be in camel case (idNumbers, names, thisIsAVariable, etc).

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `indexOf` returns -1 to indicate that the element didn't exist (i.e. they entered a non-existent ID).

Comment: Or you might - as noted by @Meike - be better off with a `Map`.